# Iphone ModalView

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a first controller (`itemDetailViewController`) :

```
- (void)loadView {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300);

    item1DetailView = [[Item1DetailView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andController:self];
    self.view = item1DetailView;
    [item1DetailView release];
}

// there is a button in my view : item1DetailView to call this method :
- (void)clickOnButtonToModalView:(id)sender{
    Item1DetailModalViewController *item1DetailModalViewController = [[Item1DetailModalViewController alloc] init];
    item1DetailModalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:item1DetailModalViewController animated:YES];
    [item1DetailModalViewController release];
}
```

In my second controller (`item1DetailModalViewController`) I've got a button for `dismissModalViewController` :

```
- (void)clickOnButtonSortirModalView:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

`item1DetailModalViewController` is close but `item1DetailView` fills the screen. The frame was : `CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300);`

Is there something I am missing?

I have tried this :

in my modal view controller :

```
@protocol Item1DetailModalViewDelegate
- (void)modalViewControllerDone;
@end
@interface Item1DetailModalViewController : UIViewController {
    Item1DetailModalView *item1DetailModalView;
    id <Item1DetailModalViewDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Item1DetailModalView *item1DetailModalView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <Item1DetailModalViewDelegate> delegate;
- (void)clickOnButtonSortirModalView:(id)sender;
@end

- (void)clickOnButtonSortirModalView:(id)sender{
    //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.delegate modalViewControllerDone];
}

In my itemDetailViewController :
@interface Item1DetailViewController : UIViewController <Item1DetailModalViewDelegate>

- (void)modalViewControllerDone {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But the problem is already exist ...

Thank you for your Help !

Comment: An advice for better naming: You should not mix French and English in your method names.

Comment: Yes you are allright I'll clear my code ! Thk

Comment: thank you 7KV7 I complete my Question !

Answer (score 0):

dismissModalViewController must be called by the controller presenting the view [1](http://Apple%20API%20doc). In your case, it's `itemDetaiViewController`.

What you need to do is add your itemDetailViewController as a delegate to the modal view controller. Then when you tap on the button, this will allow you to call:

```
- (void)clickOnButtonSortirModalView:(id)sender{
    [delegate modalViewControllerDone];
}
```

and in `itemDetailViewController`:

```
- (void)modalViewControllerDone {
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me to add itemDetailViewController as a delegate to the modal view controller ? I'm so beginner sorry ...

Comment: Do I have to implement a protocol ?

Comment: Yes you should implement a protocol. It's easy. Have a look at the Apple documentation "Modal View Controllers" http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Comment: Thank you Kamchatka I followed this documentation, but when I return on my itemDetailViewController the size of the frame is modify ... I can't understand ...